# Turn by turn directions in android app using Mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox

A colleague of mine is currently working on implementing turn by turn directions into an app that is being developed for the company we are working in. I have been tasked with trying to assist him but neither of us have been able to make any progress.

He is using Mapbox to create the map. I have never used mapbox before so I am not much help.

He has code implemented that should give us turn by turn directions but it does not seem to be doing anything whatsoever.

Sorry if I am bringing up old questions or am not stating my situation clearly but this is the best I can explain myself. We have done much searching but nothing we found seems to help.

Here is the code that he has tried using that is supposed to implement turn by turn directions.

```
private void getRoute(Waypoint origin, Waypoint destination) throws ServicesException {

    MapboxDirections client = new MapboxDirections.Builder()
            .setOrigin(origin)
            .setDestination(destination)
            .setProfile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING)
            .setSteps(true)
            // .setOverview(DirectionsCriteria.OVERVIEW_FULL)
            .setInstructions(DirectionsCriteria.INSTRUCTIONS_TEXT)
            .setAccessToken("pk.eyJ1IjoibnRyY3N2ZyIsImEiOiJCUmc4OHhjIn0.shHWdNg3Q32QUHJ1nOCs3A")
            .build();

    client.enqueue(new retrofit.Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<DirectionsResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
            Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
            if (response.body() == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                return;
            } else if (response.body().getRoutes().size() < 1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onResponse(Response<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
            // You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
            Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
            if (response.body() == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                return;
            } else if (response.body().getRoutes().size() < 1) {
                Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                return;
            }

            drawRoute(currentRoute);
        }


        private void drawRoute(DirectionsRoute route) {
            // Convert LineString coordinates into LatLng[]
            LineString lineString = LineString.fromPolyline(route.getGeometry(), Constants.OSRM_PRECISION_V5);
            List<Position> coordinates = lineString.getCoordinates();
            LatLng[] points = new LatLng[coordinates.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
                points[i] = new LatLng(

                        coordinates.get(i).getLatitude(),
                        coordinates.get(i).getLongitude());
            }

            Polyline polyline = mMapboxMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(points)
                    .color(Color.RED)
                    .width(5));
            directionsOn = true;


        }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend changing from Directions v4 to v5 found in [Mapbox Java](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#mapbox_android_services). Once you make the switch, you can work off [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/directions/) found on our website. Make sure you are also passing in coordinates in the correct order, `longitude` is given first followed by `latitude`.

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend mapbox provides detailed document with sample code snippets as well.
I have build a working app for my requirement by following mapbox turn by turn navigation documents.

please follow the link and let me know if you face any issues.

Link : https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/navigation-ui/

Here you can use NavigationView component to customise the mapbox turn by turn features.